# How to exclude rows without value?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I want to import only the agent name and its "Twitter user" but if "F" is empty then ignore it. How? I have tried "Query" but its not working. I want to import it to another sheet in the same general sheet.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:F; "select A,F where F is not null"; )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to [create a Pivot](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308944?hl=en), and add a [filter on Column](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556?hl=en) F.
A pivot creates a new view of your table, with arbitrary rows or columns. And a filter on column F allows you to eliminate rows with empty F value.

Comment: I want to do it without using filters

Comment: @Deedmunkee "I want to" is not software engineering reasoning. It's the right tool.